# Remove a certain number of elements from dropdownlist

Tags: jquery

I have a problem in jQuery. I have a dropdownlist consists of say 10 elements. Now on a checkbox click, I want to remove first five elements.

It can be also something like this: I want to remove the elements from index 0 to index 5. How to do that?

Comment: when the checkbox is clicked again should the be put back  ?

Comment: all you peopel are too fast LOL I could get my answer out in time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you ask

```
$('#checkboxID').click(function(){
  $('#dropdownID > option:lt(5)').remove();
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/VBT42/

---

If you want to just hide them while the checkbox is checked and show them again on unchecking the checkbox then use

```
$('#checkboxID').click(function(){
  $('#dropdownID > option:lt(5)').toggle();
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/VBT42/2/ (*will not work for IE though*)

---

And for a universally safe remove/restore use the [`.detach()` <sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) method and store a reference to the them with the [`.data()` <sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method

```
$('#checkboxID').click(function(){
  if (this.checked) {
       $('#dropdownID').data('removedOptions', $('#dropdownID > option:lt(5)').detach() );
  } else {
      var $dropdown = $('#dropdownID');
      $dropdown.prepend( $dropdown.data('removedOptions') );
  }
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/VBT42/4/

Comment: just a note I think to OP wanted drop down not select box

Comment: thanks .. i wish i could put all of u as ans .... can i do that ? all are correct answers :)

Comment: @mcgrailm, dropdowns are implemented through the `select` tag. I just made it `multiple` to so that you can see the options added/removed..

Comment: I know how they are implemented, see my answer 8 ^ ) i know its late but hey what can you do!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this in the checkbox click/change handler:

```
 $("#selectBox option:lt(5)").remove();
```

Comment: lt is a zero based selector so you should use lt(5)

Answer (score 1):

maybe this could work, never tried it myself:

```
$("option").each(function(index) {
if(index < 5) $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: yes but the question asker not provided a strict selector for the options.

Comment: @omnosis ... indeed Gaby is right .. the above comment is true.. i just need to delete first 5 options from a particular dropdownlist. not all.... sorry for not mentioning that :)

Answer (score 1):

adding anyhow

```
<select name="foo" id="myselect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" />
```

here's the jQuery

```
$('#mycheckbox').change(function() {
    $("#myselect option:lt(5)").toggle();
    if( $('#myselect option:lt(5)').is(":hidden") ){
        $("#myselect option:eq(5)").attr('selected','selected');
    }else{
        $("#myselect option:eq(0)").attr('selected','selected');
    }
});
```

here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/aAgEy/)

Comment: You should only change the selection when you hide them and only if the current selection is one of the hidden. (*also it does not work in IE*)

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli if fixed the select options but wasn't sure how to fix the ie issue but it looks like you got it covered. This was a good exercise thank you and @Joy

Answer (score 0):

```
$("options selector").each(function(i){if(i<5){$(this).remove();}});
```